# Redirect to dashboard after successful payment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

This is my app.js where all the routes

```
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
            <Route exact path="/payment" element={<Payment />} />]
          </Route>
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
       </Routes>
      </Router>
```

This is my PrivateRoute component

```
function PrivateRoute({ fetchMe, ...props }) {
  const [type, setType] = useState("xxxxx");
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [lodar, setLodar] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setLodar(false);
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      (async () => {
        const {
          value: { user },
        } = await fetchMe();
        console.log({ data: user.step1 });
        if (user.step === 1) {
          navigate("/payment");
        }
        setLodar(false);
      })();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Spin indicator={antIcon} spinning={lodar}>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <>
          <Header type={type} setType={setType} />
          <Outlet context={[type, setType]} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Navigate to="/login" />
      )}
    </Spin>
  );
}
export default PrivateRoute;
```

So what I want to do here is to always redirect the user to the "/payment" after signup. and if the user again comes after login then it will again redirect it to the payment page so for that I am keeping a flag in my database `user.step` and checking by api call on the PrivateRoute component.
The issue is it loads the "/dashboard" page before the `fetchUser` api call which should not happen and show some lodar before. How can I do that?

Is there any better approach doing this since I always have to make an api call?

Kindly help!!!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `<Spin indicator={antIcon} spinning={lodar}>` is conditionally rendering either a loading spinner/indicator ***or*** the wrapped `children` then I think the issue is just the initial `lodar` state value. It doesn't appear the `lodar` state is ever toggled true.

I suggest starting with an initially `true` state so the component doesn't immediately render the `Outlet` or redirect when the component mounts, prior to any auth checks happening via the `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
function PrivateRoute({ fetchMe, ...props }) {
  const [type, setType] = useState("xxxxx");
  const isAuthenticated = localStorage.getItem("authToken");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [lodar, setLodar] = useState(true); // <-- initially true

  useEffect(() => {
    setLodar(true); // <-- toggle true when starting async logic
    if (isAuthenticated) {
      (async () => {
        const {
          value: { user },
        } = await fetchMe();
        console.log({ data: user.step1 });
        if (user.step === 1) {
          navigate("/payment");
        }
        setLodar(false); // <-- clear loading when complete
      })();
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <Spin indicator={antIcon} spinning={lodar}>
      {isAuthenticated ? (
        <>
          <Header type={type} setType={setType} />
          <Outlet context={[type, setType]} />
        </>
      ) : (
        <Navigate to="/login" />
      )}
    </Spin>
  );
}
```